# UITextField in custom UITableViewCell - truncated autocorrection

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I've got that issue that i can't figure out.

it's customCell like that.

```
UITableViewCell
->ContentView
--->UItextField
```

Do You have any suggestions how to fix it?

**EDIT:**

clipsToBounds = NO didn't fix it,
even if it is last cell that bubble is truncated, changing zPos didn't fix it,
any more suggestions?

[image: truncated autocorrection]

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the `UITextField` is a subView of the `UITableViewCell`, so the textField related views should also be content of it.

Solution:
 `UIView` has a `clipsToBounds` property that controls wether contents can be drawn outside the bounds.

You just  set this to `NO`.

Comment: setClipsToBounds:NO on init for tableViewCell, contentView and UITextField don't fix it